# How to check if a string contains a particular letter/symbol/number in C#?

Tags: c#

```
string text = "Tag*";
```

I want check if my string contains `*` or not.
How do I check this in C#?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [String.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx) or [String.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to find if string contains particular `string`. If you have single character to search you can using [String.IndexOf Method (Char)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwb0bwyd.aspx)

```
if(text.IndexOf("*") > -1)
{

}
```

> Return Value Type: System.Int32 The zero-based index position of value
>   if that string is found, or -1 if it is not. If value is String.Empty,
>   the return value is 0, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Consider `text.IndexOf('*')` when it is only one character.

Answer (score 0):

```
   string[] sArray = new string[] { "*" };
   string stringToCheck = "Tag*";
   bool iscontain = sArray.Any(stringToCheck.Contains);
```

Comment: These are both way over the top for the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how come you dont know this..or how much you googled it but it can be done as follows:

```
text.Contains("*");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Following :

```
string text = "Tag*";
if(text.Contains("*"))
{
  //true 
}
else
{
 //false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension to check whether the string contains specific string

```
string yourText = "abcd*efg";

bool containStar = yourText.Contains("*");
```